# Is it possible to add a mix-blend-mode to the page's highlight (::selection)?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make it so when you highlight over something, the highlight inverses the color. I want to use `mix-blend-mode: difference` to do this, but `mix-blend mode` doesn't seem to work on the text-highlight. Here's a demo of what my code looks like:

```
::selection {
  background: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
 }
```

Is there any way to do this? I think it would look really cool with my website, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately `mix-blend-mode` [isn't allowed](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-styling) with `::selection`. It would take some creative JavaScript to get the result you want.